# Finding the smallest integer based on input

Tags: java

I have an assignment to find the minimum, maximum, and average of numbers that a user inputs. Basically, they type in positive integers, seperated by a space and Java scrolls through them and adds them up. I'm able to find the sum, the average, and the largest integers, however, I am unable to find the smallest. I thought the best way to figure this out would be to set the variable representing the smallest int equal to the variable representing the largest int outside of the loop. Then, within the loop, do something like this:

```
        if(getInt < min)
        {
            min = getInt;
        }
```

Where getInt is the user-inputted value and min is the minimum integer value. Every time I run this, though, min returns as 0.

Here is my full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class exc5
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {  
        System.out.println("Write a list of nonnegative integers, each seperated by a space. To signal the end of the list, write a negative integer. The negative integer will not be counted");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        keyboard.useDelimiter(" |\n");

        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int min = max;
        double average = 0;

        boolean notNull = true;

        while(notNull == true)
        {
            int getInt = keyboard.nextInt();

            if(getInt < 0)
            {
                notNull = false;
            }  
            else
            {          
                if(getInt > max)
                {
                    max = getInt;
                }

                if(getInt < min)
                {
                    min = getInt;
                }

                sum += getInt;
                count++;
                average = (sum)/(count);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
        System.out.println("Average = " + average);
        System.out.println("Max = " + max);
        System.out.println("Minimum = " + min);
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't compare boolean variables with constants. *while(notNull == true)* is *while(notNull)*.

Comment: Initialize your min with Integer.MAX_VALUE instead of 0

Comment: I re-organized your code and cleaned it from errors. Check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
        int max = 0;
        int min = max;
```

initializes `min` to zero. (After all, `max` hasn't become the largest integer yet.) So this:

```
                if(getInt < min)
```

will never be true. Try changing this:

```
        int min = max;
```

to this:

```
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // largest possible Java `int`
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation & answer! Will accept in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 10):

You should initially set `min` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and `max` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: I delete mine try to improve your a bit in order to have just one good answer ;) 6 answers for this... how useless it is...

Answer (score 7):

You need to start with a large `min`, not `0` (only negative numbers are less then `0`). Try this:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

This is a fairly standard pattern. Also, to be "correct", your code should also include:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

Then the full range of integer input, positive and negative, is handled.

#### Edit:

Another, more "classic" approach would be to use an object reference, rather than a primitive (which *always* has a value), so the initial state can be easily distinguished as `null`. In this case, using `Integer`, rather than `int` for the values would allow testing for `null`. If I were a university professor marking such work, I would rather see the object approach - using min/max values for primitives will work, but it's a bit of a "trick".

The code wold look like this:

```
Integer min;

while (...) {

    if (min == null || getInt < min) {
        min = getInt;
    }
}
```

And similar for `max`.

Comment: +1 Yeah, that's one of these problems that everyone inevitably runs into, so once you see the symptoms, you don't need to read the code to know answer :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Love the nickname! I'm so old I even know where it comes from :)

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks for the answer! I accepted a different one as the correct answer because he explained it a little more in depth, but I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're assigning min = 0, so obviously unless you input a number lower than 0, the minimum is 0. You should initialize min to Integer.MAX_VALUE

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

(
or also:

```
int min = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Just for hacking around :P. Use the first one! :)
)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `min` to zero, so (since the inputs are positive) none of the inputs are less than `min`.

The normal way to do this is to set the initial value of `max` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, and the initial value of `min` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

This ensures that any input value will affect at least one of `min` and `max` - usually both!

Answer (score 1):

You initialize min with 0. Try to initialize with Integer.MAX_VALUE, i.e. it would be best to do:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Otherwise, your check:

```
if(getInt < 0)
```

will break out of the loop and you will never go over 0.

Answer (score 1):

Fully working and *"cleaned"* version of your program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class exc5
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        double average = 0;
        boolean notNull = true;

        while ( notNull == true )
        {
            int getInt = keyboard.nextInt();

            if ( getInt < 0 )
                notNull = false;
            else
            {
                if ( getInt > max )
                    max = getInt;

                if ( getInt <= min )
                    min = getInt;

                sum += getInt;
                count++;
            }
        }

        average = ( sum ) / ( count );

        System.out.println( "Sum = " + sum );
        System.out.println( "Average = " + average );
        System.out.println( "Max = " + max );
        System.out.println( "Minimum = " + min );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have min set as 0 to start with so getInt will never be less. You should set min at the beginning of the loop and that will solve your issue.